# How would you test the security of a flat file processing application?

Tags: input-validation

How would you test the security of a flat file processing application?

Perhaps the question is more about how does the back-end of an application that takes a flat file with a specific template as input handle such input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key word is [**fuzzing**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzing). Essentially, you automatically run the program in question many many times, with randomized inputs and seeing if some of them cause an unexpected result.

For example, what if the input

- is empty?
- is 2 GB in size?
- is in malformed UTF-16?
- contains numbers greater than 2<sup>32</sup>-1 ?
- is encoded in Shift-JIS?

Your program has a sort of expected behavior, but it's possible that some cases were not thought of by the developers (e.g. malformed UTF-16 input) and can lead to unexpected behavior. And unexpected behavior in turn can lead to security vulnerabilities.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It makes sense and it's very clear.

Comment: @RedactedforPrivacy The answer to this question also changes depending on what language you're using, and what file structure (if any) is being processed. The threats to a C/C++ program are going to be vastly different to the threats to a C# program. If you consider JSON or XML to be a flat file format, you've got to consider potential untrusted deserialisation issues. It's very much contextual.